# How to use Netbeans Jar file in Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jar

I have developed a web service client in Netbeans through WSDL file, i have build the project and get jar file. When i run that jar file, it work fine but now i have to use this jar file in my eclipse project. But when i use this jar file i get error.
"THe type javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccesstype.cannot be resolved. "
Attach is the screenshot. 
[image]
[image]

How can i solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your classpath and probably add you WS libraries in it. Open grepcode.com and paste your missing class name in it. You will see the dependency missing.

Comment: what about other dependencies? it is good to use some dependency management system like Maven, Ant + Ivy or Gradle.

Comment: I didn't added any library in the Netbeans project? so  what  else should i add in Eclipse except then Netbeans jar file

Comment: Have you configured JDK properly in Eclipse? Not JRE.

Comment: Yes i am using Eclipse for different project and it is running fine for all others.

Comment: Do you use the same JDK in NetBeans and Eclipse? Check project JDK level and classpath.

Comment: Though i am using different machine for them..But both project are using jdk1.6